# Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server

While trying to execute this Power-shell command:

```
$site = Get-SPSite  "http://mysite/"
```

facing:

> Get-SPSite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url:
>   http://mysite/.  At line:1 char:9 
>   + $spSite = Get-SPSite <<<<  " 
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletGetSite:     SPCmdletGetSite) [Get-SPSite],
>   SPCmdletPipeBindException 
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetSite

Comment: Hi Sam, Did you ever find the reason for the error? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this user doesn't have enough permissions to get spsite.
Add him as ***SPShellAdmin*** in content database please.

```
$db = Get-SPContentDatabase -site http://sharepoint 
Add-SPShellAdmin -UserName SPSP_User -database $db
```

[reference blog](http://bramnuyts.be/en/2011/06/08/get-spweb-cannot-find-an-spweb-object-with-id-or-url/)

Comment: Get-SPContentDatabase gives the same error. I have manually found the databaseid and assigned it and added the Add-SPShellAdmin to the database. It still gives the same error after adding the user as shelladmin. I do have all requisite permissions on the contentdb.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and a coworker suggested adding the user to the SPDataAccess role in SQL for the content database.  This was all it took to resolve.

Comment: Life saver.  For me Get-SPSite was working but Get-SPWeb was not. The account already had spshelladmin and even removing and re-adding  spshelladmin didn't help.  Adding this role to the user did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same error message if the Security Token Service does not function properly. See [this blog post](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2016/04/18/cannot-find-an-spsite-object-error-from-powershell/) for the detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

Run command `$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://mysite/"`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you run the SharePoint power-shell command on the same machine(Farm) containing the site, otherwise it will not work.